# Dokku run command not entering the app the folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, docker, dokku

dokku docs says at https://dokku.com/docs/processes/one-off-tasks/ that `dokku run node-js-app ls -lah` runs `ls -lah` in the `/app` directory of the app `node-js-app`.

It was working like that for me, but recently when trying to run a command like `dokku run myapp pwd` on my dokku, it returns `/`, I would expect it to return `/app`.

`dokku run myapp cd app && bundle exec rails c` also doesn't work as I get `exec: "cd": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Any tips? (I am using dokku `0.24.7`)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is gone after updating to dokku `0.24.10` and restarting the ubuntu to install updates `sudo reboot`